# nivel de aislamiento "serializable" bloquea toda la base de datos?

Tags: sql-server, tsql, transact-sql

querria saber cuando usamos el nivel de aislamiento "Serializable" bloquea toda la base de datos completamente o solo los datos usados dentro de la transaccion?

Comment: El nivel de aislamiento superior, que es serializable, garantiza que una transacción recuperará exactamente los mismos datos cada vez que repita una operación de lectura, aunque para ello aplicará un nivel de bloqueo que puede afectar a los demás usuarios en los sistemas multiusuario

Comment: Siento ser algo rudo, pero antes de preguntar, es mejor documentarse un poco, [Documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-isolation-levels?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=El%20nivel%20de%20aislamiento%20superior,usuarios%20en%20los%20sistemas%20multiusuario.)